# How can I use the new password generated in next call of same function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, put

I have the following function which updates password of a username AFTER authentication

```
def test_put_profile(self):
    username = 'max@gmail.com'
    password = 'evkna7'
    adv = {'email': username, 'password': password}

    # genearate auth code for authorization
    auth_code = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.get_auth_token(adv)}'}

    #genearate new password
    np = DataGenerator.generate_random_password_string(6)
    param = f'old_password={password}&'f'new_password={np}'

    #update password
    response = self.send_adv_api_request(
                                         data=param,
                                         auth=auth_code)
```

Now, How can I store the new password and replace that with **password** of the same function at the beginning when I call it next time?. Basically, this is going to be the recursive test of update password.

Any help would be appreciated.  Should I write it in a text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the password outside of the scope of this function so that you can access it from your recursive calls.

```
curr_password = 'evkna7'

def test_put_profile(self):
    global curr_password
    username = 'max@gmail.com'
    adv = {'email': username, 'password': curr_password}

    # genearate auth code for authorization
    auth_code = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.get_auth_token(adv)}'}

    #genearate new password
    np = DataGenerator.generate_random_password_string(6)
    param = f'old_password={password}&'f'new_password={np}'
    curr_password = np #Change global password to newly created password

    #update password
    response = self.send_adv_api_request(
                                         data=param,
                                         auth=auth_code)
```

Comment: Thank you! I still have a question here. When this test runs second time, how the curr_password will take new value?

Comment: probably I should use external DB to store these new passwords and then use it.

Comment: @ManojKengudelu Each iteration of the code will update the curr_password variable. This way, you can use the last generated version in your next function call. Using an external DB would also work, like SQLite3, which is very simple to implement in python3